# No MaterialLocalizations found - MyApp widgets require MaterialLocalizations to be provided by a Localizations widget ancestor

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I was just trying to create an app with button which shows an alert message when the button is pressed.

But it gives me this error(Mentioned below).

I wrote this code by taking reference of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2U7S-3_rPc&list=PLlxmoA0rQ-Lw6tAs2fGFuXGP13-dWdKsB&index=13) video.

I am running the application on a live android phone using adb connect

Please help..!

Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Test",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Test")),
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: (){testAlert(context);},
              child: Text("PressMe"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  void testAlert(BuildContext context){
    var alert = AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Test"),
      content: Text("Done..!"),
    );

    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context){
          return alert;
        }
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code that i wrote. I also tried inserting the contents of testAlert() function directly into onPressed but doesn't work.

Error

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device ZUK Z2131...
Reloaded 0 of 419 libraries in 1,929ms.
I/flutter (18652): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (18652): The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter (18652): No MaterialLocalizations found.
I/flutter (18652): MyApp widgets require MaterialLocalizations to be provided by a Localizations widget ancestor.
I/flutter (18652): Localizations are used to generate many different messages, labels,and abbreviations which are used
I/flutter (18652): by the material library. 
I/flutter (18652): To introduce a MaterialLocalizations, either use a  MaterialApp at the root of your application to
I/flutter (18652): include them automatically, or add a Localization widget with a MaterialLocalizations delegate.
I/flutter (18652): The specific widget that could not find a MaterialLocalizations ancestor was:
I/flutter (18652):   MyApp
I/flutter (18652): The ancestors of this widget were:
I/flutter (18652):   [root]
I/flutter (18652): 
I/flutter (18652): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (18652): #0      debugCheckHasMaterialLocalizations.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:124:7)
I/flutter (18652): #1      debugCheckHasMaterialLocalizations (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:127:4)
I/flutter (18652): #2      showDialog (package:flutter/src/material/dialog.dart:635:10)
I/flutter (18652): #3      MyApp.testAlert (package:flutter_app/main.dart:33:5)
I/flutter (18652): #4      MyApp.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_app/main.dart:19:29)
I/flutter (18652): #5      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:507:14)
I/flutter (18652): #6      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:562:30)
I/flutter (18652): #7      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
I/flutter (18652): #8      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9)
I/flutter (18652): #9      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:175:7)
I/flutter (18652): #10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:315:9)
I/flutter (18652): #11     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:73:12)
I/flutter (18652): #12     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:11)
I/flutter (18652): #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:180:19)
I/flutter (18652): #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:22)
I/flutter (18652): #15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:138:7)
I/flutter (18652): #16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
I/flutter (18652): #17     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:85:7)
I/flutter (18652): #18     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:168:13)
I/flutter (18652): #19     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:122:5)
I/flutter (18652): 
I/flutter (18652): Handler: onTap
I/flutter (18652): Recognizer:
I/flutter (18652):   TapGestureRecognizer#d5d82(debugOwner: GestureDetector, state: possible, won arena, finalPosition:
I/flutter (18652):   Offset(220.2, 406.1), sent tap down)
I/flutter (18652): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
W/ActivityThread(18652): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@59b4e8d
I/ViewRootImpl(18652): CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is because the context you are passing into the `showDialog` method is a `context` that doesn't yet have a `MaterialLocalizations` widget in the widget tree, the `MaterialLocalizations` widget gets added implicitly by the `MaterialApp` widget.

To fix it, try the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Test",
      home: TestPage(),
    );
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Test")),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.redAccent,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {
              testAlert(context);
            },
            child: Text("PressMe"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void testAlert(BuildContext context) {
    var alert = AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Test"),
      content: Text("Done..!"),
    );

    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return alert;
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Would be nice if you provided some explanation of what exactly your code doing...

Comment: What I'm seeing is that Jordan is moving the problematic Widget into it's own statless widget class in order to not use the same `context` as what `MaterialApp()` is using.

Answer (score 51):

An easy fix which worked in my case was simply to move the MaterialApp widget up to the main() method.

```
main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: App()));
}
```

Comment: For someone who curious, this answer and the accepted answer is the same. The accepted answer using 2 parameters of MaterialApp constructor while this answer using 1 parameter MaterialApp constructor.

Answer (score 28):

This also happens when you switch to a language that is not supported by the `GlobalMaterialLocalizations` delegate. It is a tricky message to understand, because it says that you should have the `MaterialApp` at the top of your tree, but that may already be present.

In my case, the language I was localising (UK Welsh -- `cy-GB`) is not catered for automatically. I had to write my own delegate for boilerplate strings, and add it to the list of localisations at the root of my app.

The code for the Belarusian delegate is [here](https://github.com/flutter/website/blob/master/examples/internationalization/add_language/lib/main.dart). I adapted it to cater for the Welsh language. It contains date formatting information, as well as about seventy stock phrases that material design thinks you may need, such as "SELECT ALL", "Page <x> of <y>" etc.

If you need to make a delegate that covers a language not listed in the global material localisations, then once you have created the delegate, look in your codebase, and somewhere near the top of the tree, you will have a line like

```dart
MaterialApp(
 localizationsDelegates: [
   GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
   GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
   GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
 ],
 supportedLocales: [
    const Locale('en', ''), // English, no country code
    const Locale('he', ''), // Hebrew, no country code
    const Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'zh')
  ],
  // ...
)
```

Simply add `CyMaterialLocalizations.delegate` (or whatever you call your new language delegate) to the `localizationsDelegates` list.

Comment: Hi mate, I've tried this method and keep getting this error appear in the delegate I've created .. "ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Invalid locale "so")" any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Chris -- it's complaining about the DateFormat you're using inside your delegate. I had to reuse the en-GB date format in my Welsh language delegate. That in itself causes another crash (and I've raised an issue to fix it). There is a way to fix that as well. I'll add the details to my answer later. It's tricky stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate! Yea, it's complaining about all of those parameters ... Cheers for the help, appreciate it

Comment: TL;DR -- the custom delegate interferes with the GlobalMaterialLocalizations delegate if they both call initializeDateFormatting. What you can do in your delegate is remove the initializeDateFormatting call, and change to a supported date format. But then you have to be sure that GlobalMaterialLocalizations initialises date formats first even when you launch the app in Somali.

Comment: I do this by calling await GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate.load(supportedLocales[0]) in a FutureBuilder at the top of the app, where `supportedLocales` is an immutable array I have set up. It's not the ideal solution, but it works, and there is no appreciable lag.

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the response .. Unfortunately I'm still getting some errors about "so_GB" being an unsupported locale... Is there anyway I could take a peek at your edited delegate class?

[EDIT] I think it's working now even though I'm getting an error .. I forgot to add "so" to the main localization delegate

Comment: However it would still be handy to check out your new custom delegate code in full

Comment: So, where is the list of these "magical strings" like "en", "fr". Maybe i have one wrong letter. For example I need for Madagaskar. Just to be sure, that is does not exist, before creating boilerplate code.

Comment: How can you know which locale is causing this error? @RobLyndon

Comment: I can relate to this one, but actually the issue is occurring to few users and I can't reproduce it, Can you help?

Answer (score 8):

Adding `localizationsDelegates` and `supportedLocales` to `MaterialApp` solved the issue for me

```
localizationsDelegates: [
      GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
    ],

supportedLocales: [
      Locale('en', 'US'),
    ],
```

Comment: That is what worked for me and what we can find in the official documentation https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#setting-up

Comment: As mentioned in the docs, I had to add `  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter` to my pubspec.yaml file. See docs for indentation.

Answer (score 5):

Leaving this here just in case someone (like me) is using `CupertinoApp` instead of `MaterialApp` in their `MyApp` `build` function. Easiest solution I found is to simply pass `DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate` delegate to the `localizationsDelegates` param like so:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: CupertinoThemeData(),
      home: const MainScreenView(),
      localizationsDelegates: [
        DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue with a CupertinoApp and this is indeed the only hint I've found anywhere, so really, thank you!

Comment: thanks, was facing the same issue on cupertino app.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue with `showTimePicker` inside of `RaisedButton`,

I restructured as:

```
runApp 
  |__MaterialApp
    |__ StatefulWidget/StatelessWidget
      |__SafeArea
        |__Scaffold
          |__ RaisedButton
            |__ showTimePicker
```

Here is the sample  worked solution:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', 'US'), 
      ],
      home: Sample(),
    ),
  );
}

class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleState createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Time Picker'),
            onPressed: () {
              showTimePicker(
                context: context,
                initialTime: TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 47),
                builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                  return MediaQuery(
                    data: MediaQuery.of(context)
                        .copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
                    child: child,
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach by wrapping the most inner widget that invokes `showDialog` with `Builder`. In this scenario, the most inner widget is `TextButton` (note that I replaced the deprecated `RaisedButton` with `TextButton`).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Test")),
        body: Container(
          child: Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              return TextButton(
                child: const Text('Show'),
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                      title: Text("Test"),
                      content: Text("Done..!"),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Jeff Atword does not like this coding style: https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, where I need to show dailog in

```
initState();
```

which I solved like this,

```
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
  showGameOverDailog(context);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it occurred when I passed to insert this record in StatefulWidget:

```
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31580710)

Answer (score 0):

```
localizationsDelegates: [
    MonthYearPickerLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
```

I was using a MonthYearPicker package and I had to add this to my MaterialApp Widget

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue for 2 days and after 2 days small trick worked for me.

I just kept `supportedLocales: const [Locale('en', 'IN')]` and remove others.

Another way is removing `supportedLocales: const [Locale('en', 'IN')]` also worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the same error happened when I tried to open DatePicker with Locale not stated in the list of locales in MaterialApp. I had MaterialApp.router(supportedLocales: const [
Locale('en'),
Locale('es'),
]...)
and tried showDatePicker(
locale: const Locale('es_mx')...)
The error was fixed with using one of the locales listed in supportedLocales

Answer (score -2):

Build method should return **MaterialApp and NOT Scaffold.**
Within home of your Material App you can have Scaffold

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(),   //or your Page with Scaffold
    );
  }
```

Comment: the reason it will not work is because, I too got the same issue when I used scaffold inside material but actually it needs material as it's ancestor, so simply we need to split it into two classes or so....

Answer (score -2):

Easiest way to handle this problem is to rename the page to Home
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXds1.png)

Then return the Scaffold widget in the Home class

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eR3D.png)