# Flutter dialog not showing

Tags: flutter

This is my code, Here I am triggering the function `showDialog`, but that dosen't show any dialog.

```
Widget appbar(BuildContext context) {
  return PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(59.0), //AppBar Height
    child: AppBar(
      centerTitle: true, //make icon on center
      leading: Builder(
        builder: (context) => IconButton(
            icon: SizedBox(
                height: 32,
                width: 32,
                child: Image.asset('resources/icon/menu.png')),
            onPressed: () {
              if (_scaffoldBodyKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen == false) {
                _scaffoldBodyKey.currentState.openDrawer();
              } else {
                _scaffoldBodyKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
              }
            }),
      ),
      title: SizedBox(
          height: 32, width: 32, child: Image.asset('resources/icon/icon.png')),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
            icon: SizedBox(
                height: 25,
                width: 25,
                child: Image.asset('resources/icon/more.png')),
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Sfee'),
                  content: Text("dddsscsdcscs"),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        FlatButton(
                          child: Text('Okay'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                          },
                          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Comment: any error console?

Comment: make sure the `context` that is provided is the build methods context.

Comment: have try at main body also no function

Comment: have pop-up launch.json

Comment: @JeffNaa would you mind close your editor and simulator and restart??

Comment: @SamChan after restart I get a this error 

No MaterialLocalizations found.
The ancestors of this widget were
    [root]
        renderObject: RenderView#bf6b6

Comment: @JeffNaa I see, you can check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your `context` is not lost, but `context` does not have a `MaterialLocalizations` widget in the widget tree. It means that you need `MaterialApp`, like

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,//your appBar is not wrong
      body: Container() //your body
    );
  }
```

For more explanation, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56275595/no-materiallocalizations-found-myapp-widgets-require-materiallocalizations-to).

Comment: @Dude Because dialog, which is inside JeffNaa's appBar coding, is nothing wrong so far. Maybe you should figure out what is reason causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

try this format for dialog

```
showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => Dialog(
          child: Container(...),
        )
)
```